# Capturing MySQL connection error in Python

Tags: python, exception, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to handle database connection errors in Python. I have done the following:

```
try:
    dashDB = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=paramHost,
        user=paramUser,
        password=paramMySqlPwd,
        database=paramDatabase,
        port=paramMySQLPort
    )
except Exception as dashErr:
    logging.critical("%s Error connecting to MySQL:%s\n%s %s", log_time(), str(dashErr),
                     log_time(), termMSG)
    exit(1)

if dashDB is None: <-- WARNING IS ON dashDB HERE
    logging.critical("%s %s\n%s", log_time(), "Failed to connect to MySQL", termMSG)
    exit(1)
```

But still get a warning (PyCharm, at <--) that **dashDB can be undefined**.

Am I missing some exceptions that I should be trapping?

(work in progress)

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: The problem is that the variable *dashDB* will not be instantiated in case of an exception. Actually, your test (if dashDB is None) is redundant because if no Exception occurs it will not be None

Comment: I wasn't sure whether he exception caught all errors, hence the redundant check. 

From what you're saying there's nothing I can do about the warning then. Looks as though pyCharm is missing some deeper analysis - it's impossible for that point to be reached without dashDB being set. 

Help appreciated - thank you.

Comment: The *except* clause (as written) will only catch that particular Exception. Any other Exception will cause your program to terminate (unless the code you've shown is wrapped in some other *try/except* construct)

Comment: Sorry if I'm back at basics but I am new to Python - what other exceptions should I be checking for? Is there a generic check that I can use? Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: The way you've coded it will catch  the generic Exception

Comment: Got it now - thank you very much!